# I am unable to increase the size of my home partition

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, gparted, diskpart

i have installed ubuntu on my ssd along with the windows i already had(dual boot). Now, i cant increase the size of my home partition more than the size i originally allocated in windows disk manager. Since i cant do it from ubuntu using GParted, the logical solution will be to do it in the windows itself, but the thing is my windows hasn't opened since i installed ubuntu with her in the same ssd(she's a bi**h). So, the lack of space is really causing problems for me. Please tell me anything i could do, keeping losing data to last resort.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a live ubuntu usb stick, and try to do that from there.

Seems like you need something of this nature anyways to fix your problem in Windows boot. I would **NOT** advice to 'install/reinstall' any of the OSs because of possible boot problems.

Try to get Windows running first.

Comment: I did not do that but I did use the bootable USB to install Ubuntu in my HDD, which had way larger free space and transferred all my files from the OS on tge ssd and deleted the partition. After that I increased the size of the windows partition to the earlier size, but she still refuses to backoff(she truly is a bi**h) and I can run Ubuntu fine but the data in my windows, totalling to around 1TB is still inaccessible to me. I can access the files but the programs specifically made for windows are out of my reach. I'm trying hard to get out of the mess I've made, but really need help.

Comment: Do I get it correctly; 1- You have 2 disks, an ssd and an hdd. 2- Before ubuntu you had Windows OS on ssd and were using hdd for some programs and data for your Windows. 3- Then you installed ubuntu on the hdd and it somehow messed up your hdd partitons causing problems for your Windows. 4- Then you tried to fix with resizing/creating partitons. Correct ?

Comment: all correct till 3. i first installed ubuntu on the same ssd as windows. That messed up with windows. Then i tried to get out of it by installing ubuntu on HDD and deleting the ubuntu directory from the ssd, but the windows is still messed up

Comment: @MayankYadav in that case I'd suggest you to back up / salvage your data. Then try tp fix/recover your Windows disk with a Windows USB stick. Good luck. I'd suggest you get some help from a friend or alike.